# How to change a value of a variable passed through the method get in PHP

Tags: php, html, button, get

I want to be able to modify the value of a variable "Language" and pass it to the browser by clicking on a button in the page.

Basically, the user can click on a button in the web page, Then the whole page will be refreshed with different language.

Any clues how to do this with the HTML tag  ?

Here is the code that i did, but it does not work:

```
     <form method='get' action='myWebPage.php'>  
         <button type='button' name='Language' value='<?php echo $tLangValue["Language"]' ; ?> onclick='<?php if(isset($_GET['Language'])){Language=1;}else{Language=0;} ?>'>Switch Language</button>  
     </form>
```

Comment: can you please explain the question in more detail...

Comment: Does your PHP have a way to switch the language already? `$_GET['lanugage']` as passed into PHP.

Comment: You don't need a form, just a link will do. Google "passing variables to PHP"

Comment: @popnoodles : form must be used in the assignment

Comment: @Andy : Can you give more details please

Answer (score 1):

This problem is more complex than it looks on the first sight. It depends if your data will show in different language or if it is only about user interface.

When data changes, you probably want to also change their URL. So make link to different site subtree -- `http://example.com/en/` vs. `http://example.com/cz/`.

If your data are the same and only user interface changes, you can autodetect language from [Accept-Language](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.4) HTTP header. When user change language, set a cookie for entire application, to do so, you can use URL like `http://example.com/...?lang=en` and process change on server.

You can use autodetection in the first cas too, simply put autodetect script into web root, so user who visits `http://example.com/` will get instantly redirected to the version in his language.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you ckeck the small code above to see if you recognised something obvious ? Thanks